# How do I pass Fragment to class constructor by solving the error "Activity cannot be converted to Fragment"?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have Navigation drawer -> If I click item from the Navigation drawer, it opens the separate Fragment which has two tabs named as "Lists" and "Photos".

My aim is, when I click the first tab ie. "Lists tab", I am trying to call "Listclassfragment class" which has to display listview. When I click or swipe the second tab ie. photos tab, "photosfragment" class will be called and it has to show photos in grid. I am achieving this by using ViewPagerAdapter.

When I try to work on ListClassFragment, I am getting the Error,

> Error :  incompatible types: Activity cannot be converted to ListClassFragment

**ListClassFragment class:**

```
public class ListClassFragment extends Fragment {
private ListView listview;
private ArrayList<ListView_Model> books;
private ArrayAdapter<ListView_Model> adapter;

private final static String TAG = ListClassFragment.class.getSimpleName();

private final static String url = "http://myfee.org/apps/customer?id=1";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_listview, container, false);

    listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    setListViewAdapter();
    getDataFromInternet();
    return view;

}

private void getDataFromInternet() {
    new GetJsonFromUrlTask(getActivity(), url).execute();

}

private void setListViewAdapter() {
    books = new ArrayList<ListView_Model>();
    adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item_listview, books);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
}

//parse response data after asynctask finished
public void parseJsonResponse(String result) {
    Log.i(TAG, result);
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(json.getString("customer"));

        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

            ListView_Model book = new ListView_Model();
            book.setName(jObject.getString("name"));
            book.setAuthorName(jObject.getString("email"));
            book.setPhoneNo(jObject.getString("phone_no"));


            /*Pay Button here*/
            book.setImageUrl1(R.drawable.custom_button);

            books.add(book);
        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

**GetJsonFromUrlTask class:**

```
public class GetJsonFromUrlTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

private Activity activity;
private String url;
private ProgressDialog dialog;
private final static String TAG = GetJsonFromUrlTask.class.getSimpleName();

public GetJsonFromUrlTask(Activity activity, String url) {
    super();
    this.activity = activity;
    this.url = url;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    // Create a progress dialog
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    // Set progress dialog title
    dialog.setTitle("Loading Datas....");
    // Set progress dialog message
    dialog.setMessage("Please wait!!");
    dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    // Show progress dialog
    dialog.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

    // call load JSON from url method
    return loadJSON(this.url).toString();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    ((ListClassFragment) activity).parseJsonResponse(result);
    dialog.dismiss();
    Log.i(TAG, result);
}

public JSONObject loadJSON(String url) {
    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONGetter jParser = new JSONGetter();

    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    return json;
}

private class JSONGetter {

    private InputStream is = null;
    private JSONObject jObj = null;
    private String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONGetter() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"),
                    8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}}
```

Comment: use GetJsonFromUrlTask class as inner class in your fragment

Comment: How to cast activity to fragment?? How can you cast an activity to fragment? Activity is a Component class Child of **ContextThemeWrapper** and Fragment is used as part of an activity. 

You can access an Activity from its child fragment by getActivity(). If this  doesn't answer your question then change the title of question .

Comment: How can you cast an orange to a pineapple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to pass Fragment to class constructor. Change code like this

```
private ListClassFragment listFragment;
private String url;
private ProgressDialog dialog;
private final static String TAG = GetJsonFromUrlTask.class.getSimpleName();

public GetJsonFromUrlTask(ListClassFragment listFragment, String url) {
    super();
    this.listFragment = listFragment;
    this.url = url;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    listFragment.parseJsonResponse(result);
    dialog.dismiss();
    Log.i(TAG, result);
}
```

And in ListClassFragment class:

```
private void getDataFromInternet() {
    new GetJsonFromUrlTask(this, url).execute();
}
```

Comment: pass to dialog constructor listFragment.getActivity() or better listFragment.getContext()

Comment: Superb! Working fine now... Thanks to you :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Its better to do it with a callback(an Interface). Below is an exxample

```
public class GetJsonFromUrlTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    private String url;
    private NetworkCallback callback;

    public GetJsonFromUrlTask(String url, NetworkCallback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Do your stuffs
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        // OnSuccess
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.onNetworkSuccess(s);
        }

        // On error
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.onNetworkException(exception);
        }
    }

    public interface NetworkCallback {
        void onNetworkSuccess(String response);

        void onNetworkException(Exception e);
    }
}
```

Calling can be as below or you can directly `implements` your fragment by `NetworkCallback`.

```
 private void getDataFromInternet() {
    new GetJsonFromUrlTask(url, new NetworkCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onNetworkSuccess(String response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNetworkException(Exception e) {

        }
    }).execute();

}
```

Modify the interface as per your need .